# report builder Parameters order

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportbuilder

can someone explain to me why when I do a report with Power Bi report builder the parameters that I use distribute in a disorganized way?
[image]

as you can see there are like 4 columns for the parameters: but in the first row, the third column is empty, and in the second row the first one is. I thought that was the length of the parameters, but it doesn't matter what i put as the first 3/4 parameters, they will be always arranged like that. Where i can fix that?

Comment: you should be able to drag them in the report designer. What version of SSRS are you targeting?

Comment: as long as you are using ssrs 2016 and above, you should be able to reorganise the parameter section by simply dragging it to where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

In View menu, check Parameters.
It will appear in Design mode the Parameters and you can Drag and Drop your order.

[image]